# Production ready Slack App without using ngrok hosted in C# WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, production, ngrok, slack-commands

I'm new to developing Slack apps. I've created a slack app with slash command feature by reading online blogs. Slash command is implemented in a C# WebApi hosted in a windows service. All these blogs are written using third party tools like ngrok for localhost tunneling. As i understand, ngrok is only used during dev/testing phases. How does it work in production deployments without using ngrok? Please note that my slack app is only for internal use within my company, not for public. So, how does Slack will reach my WebApi endpoint hosted in a Windows service running on some local machine with in my company without any third party tools like ngrok?

Comment: Your web api needs to be publicly accessible so that Slack's servers can reach it. ngrok provides a tunnel so that you can provide a public endpoint to Slack that is actually served from your localhost where you develop, which is convenient for development.

Is there a reason why it'd need to run on a windows machine that is physically sitting in your local company, versus a web host (azure, aws, etc) ?

Comment: Ultimately, to stop using ngrok, your production deployment will have to be somewhere that has the endpoint's port accessible to the public internet, whether that is a server that sits in-house or using a cloud provider like Azure.

Comment: THanks mmccaff for taking time to post on my issue. Yeah, seems those are the only two options I have.